# Extract information from web streams

Tags: c#, winforms, websocket, stream, lightstreamer

Is it possible to extract information from websites that provide streaming of data? For example, the web page https://www.lightstreamer.com shows a demo where prices keep changing.

Using Google Chrome Developer (F12, Network, WS, Reload page with F5, Select name "lightstreamer") , I found out that the stream is being sent from wss://push.lightstreamer.com/lightstreamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of client with full source on [github](https://github.com/Lightstreamer/lightstreamer-example-BandwidthandFrequency-client-javascript).

The following line shows how to target a demo server

```
var lsClient = new LightstreamerClient(protocolToUse+"//localhost:"+portToUse,"DEMO");
```

Another example - this in .NET - is [here](https://github.com/Lightstreamer/Lightstreamer-example-StockList-client-dotnet) and it's based on a connection listener

```
using Lightstreamer.DotNet.Client;

namespace DotNetStockListDemo
{

    class StocklistConnectionListener : IConnectionListener
```

You can read also that [this](https://github.com/Lightstreamer/Lightstreamer-example-HelloWorld-adapter-dotnet)

> `HelloWorldAdapter` class implements the `IDataProvider` interface
>   (which is the .NET remote equivalent of the Java DataProvider
>   interface).

and find more implementation details in the docs there.